# Custom Carousel view Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, carousel

I am new in xamarin Forms, I want to do Custom Carousel View by making part of previous item and part of next item in Carousel List show with the current item in list.
I Found this plugin make exactly my need [https://github.com/NAXAM/carousel-xamarin-forms ]
But this work for Android only, i want like that for ios also.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this source: https://www.nuget.org/packages/CarouselView.FormsPlugin/
I tried and it worked the same as Naxam's library but more stable.

Comment: ,I tried to use it but did not know how get carousel as Naxam's library , i want to show part of previous item , part of next item and current item in carousel

Comment: There is an example of using this carousel view: https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView

Answer (score 0):

You can check https://github.com/sthewissen/KickassUI.ParallaxCarousel

Here is the tutorial https://www.thewissen.io/creating-a-parallax-carousel-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: thanks for replay but i want to make overlap between items in carousel